# create a model package with schemas to install it in different apps node.js

Tags: node.js

i have two apps (web app and mobile app) both apps share the same db, so what im trying to do is to create a package with the models of the db so i can use this package in both app, so this way i any modificacion in the db i can easily come to this package and do the modifications needed and models in both apps are updated.

i new with node.js so i dont have too much experience with that, im know this can be done in java, because i have done it before... i was wondering if this can be done in node.js or if there is another approach to do it.

i tried to do like this:

created a package with two main files:

root/index.js

```
class Common {
    constructor() {
        this.models = {};
    }
    init(mongoose) {
        mongoose.connect('your mongodb connection string goes here');
        require('./models/facilityModel');
        //add more model references here
        //This is just to make referencing the models easier within your apps, so you don't have to use strings. The model name you use here must match the name you used in the schema file
        this.models = {
            facilityModel: mongoose.model('facilities')
        };
    }
}

var common = new Common();

export default common;
```

root/models/faciliyModel.js

```
import { Schema, model } from 'mongoose';

const FacilitiesSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  }
});

const Facilities = model('facilities', FacilitiesSchema);

module.exports = Facilities;
```

root/package.json

```
 "main": "index.js",
```

do the npm install <>

but i keep getting this error in the import declaration

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '***'. '******' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/models` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'models/src/index';`ts(7016)
```